# What should I do when the server is unreachable during logging out

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, frontend

### Situations:

1. I am using express + node.js server.
2. The server maintains a session for every logged user.
3. The server set a cookie with session-id for logged users.
4. The server works perfectly when the user logged in.

### Questions:

What if the server is unreachable for some network error when user want to logout?
The browser may still keep that session-id in cookies. What's the most **common** way to handle this situation?

Comment: Sessions cookies should have a finite lifetime

Comment: So the session times out and the cookie will be invalid when they try to log in.

Comment: @Liam If the lifetime has 3 mouths. Then this mistake will stay there for 3 months?

Comment: Why would the lifetime be 3 months for a session?

Comment: Well don't set it for 3 months...

Comment: So the most common way to handle this question is to invalid all cookies? @epascarello

Comment: Maybe you don't know that cookies have an [expires header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)?

Comment: A session normally has a set time. The session id is linked to that set time. If the session on the server is over that time and the cookie exists it does nothing. It is like you changed the lock on your door, but still have the old key. The key does nothing so you have to ask for the new one.

Comment: Then how long should be the most suitable __set time__ for session-id?

Comment: The server side session should have a short lifetime (minutes) and you should not rely on cookie expiration alone (could be tampered). Use cookie as a bypass for login (months) which is stored in db. You can let such a disconnected user to revoke unwanted sessions from inside your app. So the cookie you are talking about is not what is generally known as `session cookie`.

Comment: what do you mean by __use cookie as a bypass for login__ ? @Xaqron

Comment: @欧阳维杰: The same as `remember me` behavior on websites so as long as browser sends the cookie, you check it against db, load user session into server memory and app knows the user.

Comment: *what do you mean by use cookie as a bypass for login*: I get a hold of your 3 month cookie. I can now pretend to be you on the web site that you use this for. Cookies are not secure.

Comment: I see ... So the pointer here is that I have to revoke those cookies every time when a user logs out? @Xaqron

Comment: @欧阳维杰 That's not your case here. For a cookie which is mapped to the server memory use expiration period such as 30 minutes so in case of disconnection/inactivity user will be logged out after 30m and server memory is released. Even if browser sends the cookie the next day, server doesn't recognize such a cookie after 30 minutes of last activity and all resources are released.

Comment: So the problem here is about frontends and backend.  I have to revoke those cookies whenever a user logs out on the frontends. And I don't need to do anything on the backend, because the server will release that session after a specified time automatically. @Xaqron

Comment: @欧阳维杰: The opposite. You need to do all the work at the backend (server). Keeping track of assigned cookies and removing data from memory after 30 seconds. The only thing frontend can do id redirecting to login page when server says the provided cookie by client is not valid (doesn't exist, expired, invalid).

Comment: Yes, that's the normal approach. I mean in my situation described above. When the server doesn't know if a user is logged out, but the user actually had clicked the log out button.@Xaqron